# Regular expression of substitution using vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to find a word and replace what's before/after the word(prefixing/postfixing)

I'm using vim editor and there are thousands of lines of code.

Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Sample input and output? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So assuming you define a word as a string of letters you probably want something like this. Replaces the word before `fred` with `newword`:

```
:%s/[a-zA-Z]\{1,\} fred/newword fred/g
```

Answer (score 0):

- Prefixing with `foo-`:

  ```
  :%s/pattern/foo-&/g
  ```
- Postfixing with `-foo`:

  ```
  :%s/pattern/&-foo/g
  ```

In the replacement part of the command, `&` represents the whole matched text. You can use `\0` as well.